# List Index out of range in python?

Tags: python

I'm kind of new to python and needed help with this - it says list index out of range?

```
file=open("Reg_Details.csv","r")
Reg=[line.split(',') for line in file]
file=open("Speed_Exceeded.csv","r")
Speed=[line.split(',') for line in file] 

for x in Reg:
    for y in Speed:
        if x[2]==y[2]:
            print("match")
            file=open("Details_user.csv","w")
            file.write("%s,%s,%s\n" % (x[0],[0],x[1])) 
file.close()
```

[(Original screencap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqGCH.png)

Comment: Post your code in the question in a code block. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the list doesn't have an element with the index id you're asking for.

```
>>> variable = [1,2,3]
>>> variable[2]
3
>>> variable[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

In this example the valid `id`s are `0`, `1` and `2`, but `3` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

When you check
    x[2] == y[2]
you're accessing the third element of each of the two lists (0 is the first element). The error you are getting means that either x or y has less than 3 elements, so the element you are asking for is out of range. Most likely Reg_Details.csv or Speed_Exceeded.csv have only 1 or 2 columns.

Also looking at your code, you probably want to replace

```
file=open("Details_user.csv", "w")
```

by

```
file=open("Details_user.csv", "a")
```

The opening mode "w" puts the writing stream at the beginning of the file, so every time you run this line you are erasing whatever was inside before (meaning each iteration of your loop you are deleting the previous line, and at the end "Details_user.csv" will contain only one line). Using the opening mode "a" (from 'append') opens the file putting the writing stream at the end of the file, so you will append a new line to the file at every iteration.